# Microsoft authentification with Firebase React-Native

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I am currently implementing a Firebase React Native connection with Microsoft. But on https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth , there is no section on Microsoft. I searched the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth
But I find it difficult to understand. I'm just trying to make a connection, nothing else.

Comment: the second documention seems to good. Please read only before you begin section. you just need to add firebase to your react-native project and enable microsoft provider on sign-in method tab.Let me know where you are finding difficulties to understand?

Comment: You can follow this document as well for the clarification : https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a connection with Microsoft Azure AD with Firebase React Native application.

Please follow the below steps to get this implemented.

> To sign in users using Microsoft accounts (Azure Active Directory and
> personal Microsoft accounts), you must first enable Microsoft as a
> sign-in provider for your Firebase project:
>
> 1. [Add Firebase to your Android project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).
> 2. In the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), open the **Auth** section.
> 3. On the **Sign in method** tab, enable the **Microsoft** provider.
> 4. Add the **Client ID** and **Client Secret** from that provider's developer console to the provider configuration:
> 5. To register a Microsoft OAuth client, follow the instructions in [Quickstart: Register an app with the Azure Active Directory v2.0
>    endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-register-an-app).
>    Note that this endpoint supports sign-in using Microsoft personal
>    accounts as well as Azure Active Directory accounts. [Learn
>    more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview)
>    about Azure Active Directory v2.0.
> 6. When registering apps with these providers, be sure to register the *.firebaseapp.com domain for your project as the redirect domain
>    for your app.
> 7. Click **Save**.
> 8. If you haven't yet specified your app's SHA-1 fingerprint, do so from the [Settings
>    page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general/)
>    of the Firebase console. Refer to [Authenticating Your
>    Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) for
>    details on how to get your app's SHA-1 fingerprint.
>
> Reference: [Authenticate Using Microsoft on Android | Firebase
> Documentation
> (google.com)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth)

You Can also refer this document for more clarification : https://medium.com/seed-digital/using-microsoft-azure-identity-with-firebase-in-a-react-native-app-c9eef0fd0af8